# Why does iOS background refresh force the app back to the Home page after X minutes? Can we control X?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a IOS app and i am facing a problem.
In this app my first screen is **Login screen** and Next screen is **User's List screen**.
When i open app i got **Login screen**. i done Login and got **User's list screen**. Now i clicked on **iPhone HOME** button. And after some time or x minutes my phone gets into the sleep mode. When i again open my phone app does not show me my current **User's List screen**. App show me the **login screen**. Can we control the time or increase time if yes then how. Please explain.

Comment: this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49091582/1042817

Answer (score 1):

Your app is being terminated by iOS, so when you re-select it, it starts again from the first screen. This won't just happen when your device sleeps but whenever iOS needs more memory and determines that terminating your app is the best way to get it.

You cannot stop termination from happening but you can manage it and move your app to the correct screen on startup. See ['Preserving Your App's UI Across Launches'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/preserving_your_app_s_ui_across_launches) in Apple's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate you need to call to restore the state :

```
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication, 
    shouldRestoreApplicationState coder: NSCoder) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you Deviyani & Olcay.. for your sugggestion.. I done changes as per your suggestion.. and i found that this is not working.